# distinct clause doesn't produce expected result

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I'd like to have one row for each different hadm_id this is my query :

```
select  
        DISTINCT (hadm_id) as Admission_ID,
        subject_id as  Patient_ID,  
        icustay_id as Care_Unit_ID , 
        intime  as In_Time ,
        outtime Out_Time,
        age as Age,
        heartrate_max as Heartrate_max,
        --  heartrate_min as Heartrate_min,
        sysbp_max as Systolic_Blood_Pressure_max,
        -- sysbp_min as Systolic_Blood_Pressure_min,
        tempc_max as Temperature_max,
        -- tempc_min as Temperature_min, 
        pao2fio2_vent_min as PAO2_FIO2,
        urineoutput as Urine_Otput, 
        -- bun_min as Blood_Urea_Nitrogen_min, 
        bun_max as Blood_Urea_Nitrogen_max,
        wbc_min as White_Blood_Cells_min, 
        -- wbc_max as White_Blood_Cells_max,
        -- potassium_min as Potassium_min, 
        potassium_max as Potassium_max, 
        -- sodium_min as Sodium_min,
        sodium_max as Sodium_max, 
        -- bicarbonate_min as Bicarbonate_min, 
        bicarbonate_max as Bicarbonate_max,
        -- bilirubin_min as Bilirubin_min, 
        bilirubin_max as Bilirubin_max, 
        mingcs as mingcs, aids as aids,
        hem as hem, 
        mets  as mets, 
        admissiontype as admissiontype, 
        resprate_max as resprate_max,
        pco2 as pco2, 
        infection as infection, 
        organ_dysfunction as organ_dysfunction 
from sepsiscategories   
-- where hadm_id in (select DISTINCT(hadm_id) from sepsiscategories) and subject_id in (select DISTINCT(subject_id) from sepsiscategories)
-- group by
-- hadm_id,subject_id
order by hadm_id asc 
limit 100
```

the result is not what I am expecting:

```
admission_id | patient_id | care_unit_id |       in_time       |     out_time        |  age  | heartrate_max | systolic_blood_pressure_max | temperature_max  |    pao2_fio2     | urine_otput |> blood_urea_nitrogen_max | white_blood_cells_min | potassium_max | sodium_max | bicarbonate_max | bilirubin_max | mingcs | aids | hem | mets |    admissiontype    | resprate_max | pco2 | inf
100003       |      54610 |       209281 | 2150-04-17 15:35:42 | 2150-04-19 14:12:52 | 59.91 |           104 |                         146 | 36.7777777777778 |                  |        2580 |                      51 |                  13.4 |           5.7  |        133 |              21 |           5.5 |     14 |      |     |      | Medical             |           21 |   29 |         0 |                 0
100006       |       9895 |       291788 | 2108-04-06 15:50:15 | 2108-04-11 15:18:03 | 48.92 |           127 |                         149 | 36.5555572509766 |                  |        2950 |                      16 |                   9.6 |           4.4  |        131 |              24 |               |     15 |      |   1 |      | Medical             |           29 |   37 |         1 |                 0
100006       |       9895 |       291788 | 2108-04-06 15:50:15 | 2108-04-11 15:18:03 | 48.92 |           127 |                         149 | 36.5555572509766 |                  |        2950 |                      16 |                   9.6 |           4.4  |        131 |              24 |               |     15 |      |   1 |      | Medical             |           29 |   40 |         1 |                 0
100006       |       9895 |       291788 | 2108-04-06 15:50:15 | 2108-04-11 15:18:03 | 48.92 |           127 |                         149 | 36.5555572509766 |                  |        2950 |                      16 |                   9.6 |           4.4  |        131 |              24 |               |     15 |      |   1 |      | Medical             |           29 |   48 |         1 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   30 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   35 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   37 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   39 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   40 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   41 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   44 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   45 |         0 |                 0
100009       |        533 |       253656 | 2162-05-17 10:18:31 | 2162-05-19 22:05:14 | 60.80 |            92 |                         132 |                  |              126 |        2490 |                      13 |                  12.3 |           4.9  |        143 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | UnscheduledSurgical |           37 |   59 |         0 |                 0
100011       |      87977 |       214619 | 2177-08-29 04:52:21 | 2177-09-09 16:56:35 | 21.50 |           142 |                         165 | 38.7222222222222 | 308.333333333333 |        5160 |                      12 |                   7.6 |           4.5  |        144 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | Medical             |           30 |   33 |         1 |                 0
100011       |      87977 |       214619 | 2177-08-29 04:52:21 | 2177-09-09 16:56:35 | 21.50 |           142 |                         165 | 38.7222222222222 | 308.333333333333 |        5160 |                      12 |                   7.6 |           4.5  |        144 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | Medical             |           30 |   35 |         1 |                 0
100011       |      87977 |       214619 | 2177-08-29 04:52:21 | 2177-09-09 16:56:35 | 21.50 |           142 |                         165 | 38.7222222222222 | 308.333333333333 |        5160 |                      12 |                   7.6 |           4.5  |        144 |              24 |               |     15 |      |     |      | Medical             |           30 |   47 |         1 |                 0
```

How can I do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` operates on the whole dataset, not a particular column. So you get one record per distinct combination of all values in *all columns* returned by the query.

Since you are using Postgres, you might want to try `DISTINCT ON`. This gives you one record per group *defined in the ON clause*. The `ORDER BY` clauses determines which row should be returned in each group.

In your query:

```
select
     distinct on(hadm_id) hadm_id as Admission_ID,
     subject_id as  Patient_ID,  
     icustay_id as Care_Unit_ID , 
     ...
from sepsiscategories   
order by hadm_id, intime
limit 100
```

This would give you one record per `hadm_id`, with the record that has the smallest `intime`. You would need to adapt the `order by` clause with the correct column for your use case.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `select distinct on(hadm_id)   hadm_id as Admission_ID, …` though?